# How to set form field for arrayfield in django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a field  by the name related in my model

```
related=ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),null=True)
```

I want this field to appear as a choicefield with multiple selection. How do i set the field in my form to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with third party multi select field. [link](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/)